# Constantly checking for network connection across the entire application

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an application that grabs its data from an external API. Whenever a user attempts to make a connection and is not connected, they receive the ugly red screen of death.

I've been playing around with `NetInfo` to alleviate this, specifically `NetInfo.isConnected`.

The way my `render` logic is structured, I don't think that I can get `this.state.isConnected === false` to actually trigger -- even when I purposefully disconnect the internet in iOS Simulator. If I set this logic to fire off its `AlertIOS.Alert` method when `this.state.isConnected` returns any falsy value, it will fire off that unpleasant alert **even if the user has a connection, because `getInitialState` sets it to `null` initially** . How should I go about fixing this?

Additionally, should I expect to recreate this logic for all of my components, since I have a feeling I'll need to almost constantly check for network access?

===

Here's my `getInitialState` lifecycle method

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      accessToken: false,
      isConnected: null,
      selectedTab: 'products'
    }
  },
```

Then in `componentWillMount`, I set up an event listener for `NetInfo.isConnected` as well as manually fetch my connection status:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectivityChange)
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((data) => {
      console.log(this.state.isConnected);
      this.setState({
        isConnected: data
      })
    })
  },
```

Once my `componentDidMount`, I check to see if my `isConnected` boolean returns true **and** my `accessToken` doesn't exist. If both conditions are met, I make an API call for my token:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.state.isConnected && !this.state.accessToken){
      api.getToken()
        .then((responseData) => {
          this.setState({
            accessToken: responseData.access_token,
          });
        })
        .done();
    }
  },
```

I also handle the removal of my event listener for `componentWillUnmount`:

```
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      'change',
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  },
```

The `handleConnectivityChange` callback for my event listener is:

```
  handleConnectivityChange: function(change) {
    this.setState({
      isConnected: change
    })
    console.log("I have changed!" + change)
  },
```

And finally, my `render` method returns one of three things based on my connectivity status:

```
  render: function() {
    if (this.state.isConnected === 'null') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Loading
            loaded={this.state.isConnected} />
        </View>
        )
    }
    if (this.state.isConnected === 'false') {
      return (
        <View>
          {AlertIOS.alert('You need to be connected to the internet!')}
        </View>
        )
    }
    return (
      <TabBarIOS>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          title='Home'
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'products'}
          iconName={'home'}
          iconSize={20}
          onPress={() => {
            if (this.state.selectedTab !== 'products') {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'products'
              });
            } else if (this.state.selectedTab === 'products') {
              this.refs.productRef.popToTop();
            }
          }}>
          {this.renderProductView()}
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          title="Collections"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'collections'}
          iconName={'list'}
          iconSize={20}
          onPress={() => {
            if (this.state.selectedTab !== 'collections') {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'collections'
              });
            } else if (this.state.selectedTab === 'collections') {
              this.refs.collectionRef.popToTop();
            }
          }}>
          {this.renderCollectionView()}
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          title="About"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'about'}
          iconName={'info'}
          iconSize={20}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'about'
            });
          }}>
          {this.renderAboutView()}
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
      </TabBarIOS>
      )
  },
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off coding for the lack of connectivity inside the network call? e.g. api.getToken().catch((error) => {})

Comment: Perfect, adding a catch worked.

Comment: Great :) I should have added it as an answer! :)

Comment: I'm also wondering if I should still have an event listener for situations where the user does reconnect later, so I don't force them to have to force quit the app in order to proceed.

Comment: Not sure that I understand. You should need to if the promise is still returned from the error rather than halting the whole thing. Just handle the error, flag something and move on? If you're referring to not having the token just add a listener for AppState changes and try everytime the app loads until you have it?

Comment: Just want to clarify: Use AppState to set an event listener for changes, and every time the app loads I should check to see if the API token is received. Will this listener have to go onto every component in my application?

Comment: I'm not sure of your full logic but I would have had the functions handling the token in the top level of the app and passed access to these functions - as well as an object containing all the data that you need - down to each child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82854/discussion-between-richard-kho-and-moss-palmer).

Comment: I'll jump on in a bit. Just got a few things to get done.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up structuring my application the following way:

First, I added a `catch` statement to my asynchronous API calls. They look like this:

```
  getCollectionsData: function() {
    api.getFeaturedCollections(this.props.accessToken)
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          featuredCollectionsDataSource: this.state.featuredCollectionsDataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.collections),
          loaded: true
        })
      })
    .then(() => {
      api.getAllCollections(this.props.accessToken)
        .then((responseData) => {
          this.setState({
            allCollectionsDataSource: this.state.allCollectionsDataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.collections),
          })
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      AlertIOS.alert('Error', 'You need to be connected to the internet')
    })
    .done()
  },
```

I also moved the API call logic into its own function, and call it during `componentWillMount`.

Then, I add a change listener for AppState.IOS, which checks for an application running in the foreground/background:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    AppStateIOS.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  },
```

My handler for these changes simply calls `getCollectionsData`.

Comment: In your catch the error can be something different from lack of internet. For example if you pass a wrong parameter, the server is down, there is no data and so on. Then the alert is not appropriate.